# Module export function, how to wait for value before returning?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I need help understanding async calls. I have a javascript function, where I need to wait before returning true or false.

**Code**

```
module.exports = function () {

var LaunchDarkly = require('ldclient-node');
var ld_client = LaunchDarkly.init("ID here");

var featureStatus;

ld_client.once('ready', function () {
    ld_client.toggle("Flag here", { "key": "Mail here" }, false, function (err, show_feature) {
        if (show_feature) {
            featureStatus = true;
        }
        else {
            featureStatus = false;
        }
    });

});

return featureStatus;

}
```

When I call this function, it will return asap with a undefined value of featureStatus. Should I use promises in this case?

Good day.

Comment: There is no way for the function to *return* the result of the asynchronous call, at all; it's not a matter of how long to wait, it just cannot be done. Details in the linked duplicate target.

Comment: ohh okay.. looking into it right now.

Comment: Yes, use promises.